# IIS: Request with unknown content-type denied

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, mime-type

I have an IIS7.5 box running an asp.net mvc 3 application. The application receives binary POST requests and returns a binary answer. To distinguish this binary data from all other packets I setup my own mime-type (let's call it *application/my.binary.data*) that I use together with the *Content-Type* header.

The IIS-server does not seem to like my own mime-type and rejects the packet with a *400 Bad Request*. If I change the mime-type to *application/octet-stream* it gets through IIS and I get an answer from my application.

How do I set IIS to allow my own mime-type for requests?

***Request packet***

```
POST http://my.local.domain/Page  HTTP/1.1
Host: my.local.domain
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: application/my.binary.data
Cache-Control: no-cache

..............p.00000000000000...
```

***Response packet:***

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 08:11:27 GMT
Content-Length: 11

Bad Request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the problem by following the following guide at http://www.donnfelker.com/aspnet-mvc-iis7-and-bad-request/.

I added the following code to my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode=”Detailed” />
</system.webserver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this blog here: http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx may shed light on what you need to do.

Mainly its update the static content settings in your applications web.config so that IIS7.5 knows about your own mime type.

Comment: Isn't this only for serving static content? I want to POST binary content into my asp.net application.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Tired brain, I miss read your question the first time. Why do you need to differenciate your mime type coming in?

Comment: I'm using it to distinguish which packets are valid and which aren't in my asp.net code.

Comment: I'm not understanding the why you would need to do that, surely if the binary data doesn't match what is expected your site should just return an error to the user? Or are you handling multiple mime types here?

Comment: The page returns an error to the user if the wrong mime-type is specified. I see it as one of many security precautions to stop unwanted traffic to these specific addresses, the earlier I stop it the better chance I have to avoid attacks. It may be an unneeded precaution but I like it to stay that way as long as it's possible.

Comment: Is this unwanted traffic from people viewing a page on your site, or from 3rd Party systems? Do you know who you want the data from? I've got a better idea of what to suggest to you.

Comment: @ITHedgeHog let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/737/discussion-between-m-and-ithedgehog)